# jQuery instantiate plugin and then call a function within it again

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Hey all I am looking for a way to call **ToggleState** *after* I already [instantiated](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/instantiate) it.

The jQuery call to do this is as follows:

```
var test = $('#demo5').btnSwitch({
    Theme: 'Swipe', 
    OnText: "Active", 
    OffText: "Inactive", 
    ToggleState: true,
    OnValue: true,
    OffValue: false,
    OffCallback: function (val) {
        alert('you selected ' + val);
    },
    OnCallback: function(val) {
        alert('you selected ' + val);
    }
});
```

I've tried to do the following **after** the above code is executed:

```
test.btnSwitch({ToggleState: false});
```

When executing the above it doesn't give an error but it also doesn't flip the switch from **true** -> **false** as it should.

What would I be doing that is incorrect in calling that?

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dgeqf5k4/)

Comment: Depends on how and what `btnSwitch` is. Ultimately this is an implementation detail of whatever plugin that is. If the plugin doesn't expose this switch, then you can't change it

Comment: @Liam Then how would I go about adding that to the script if said function is not exposed? Can you give an example?